# react native flatlist rendering sequence

Tags: javascript, react-native

im trying to render a list and assign my `SkillImageTapAction` an index to use later but it seems only the last index from the list is saved in each case

This is the flat list

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 16, marginBottom: 48 }}>
      <FlatList
       data={matchedHelpers}
       renderItem={matchedHelper => renderHelperCell(matchedHelper, props)}
       keyExtractor={(matchedHelper: any) => matchedHelper.uid}
       numColumns={1}
       ListFooterComponent={<ListFooter />}
      />
</View>
```

And this is the render item

```
 const renderHelperCell = (itemProps, props) => {
        const { item } = itemProps;
        const { index } = itemProps;
        console.log("Index-->",index)
        return (
            <HelperCell matchedHelper={item} props={props} skillImageTapAction={() => {
                setImages(item.matchedSkill.images);
                console.log("Index2-->",index)
                setTappedIndex(index)
                setShowImageSlider(true);

            }} />
        );
    };
```

Comment: How `matchedHelpers` looks like?